# React: in mobile browsers button onClick hadler fires multiple times. Desktop ones are fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, browser

I have quite simple React page with download buttons embedded:

```
<button
  type='button'
  className='button'
  onClick={this._downloadArchive}
  style={{width: '100%'}}
  >
   <div style={styles.archiveButton}>
    <div>Download</div>
    <div>{'archive.zip'}</div>
    </div>
</button>
```

And correspomding handler:

```
_downloadArchive = () => {
  let filename = 'archive.zip';
  let url = '/beta/archive32?filename=' + filename + screenDetails;
  window.open(url)
};
```

In desktop browsers it works with no issue, but in all mobile browsers handler is called multiple (3-4, depends on device and browser) times with 100-300ms delay between calls - I can see it in backend logs.
Meanwhile mobile browser downloads the file only once.
How to prevent such behaviour?

Tried to use onTouchEnd event (with detecting mobile client) - result is the same

Comment: Can you post some online mini example for the problem?

Comment: Exact code is above, what else may be needed? Backend works with no issues, the problem persists only in mobile browsers, as stated

Comment: Did you try _downloadArchive = (e) => {e.preventDefault(); ....

Answer (score 0):

Can you from text response parse to json with JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code, it does not seem to be a problem with React event handlers. Can you check if this works?

```js
_downloadArchive = (e) => {
  e.stopPropogation();
  let filename = 'archive.zip';
  let url = '/beta/archive32?filename=' + filename + screenDetails;
  window.open(url)
};
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation